# GWT using domain models /services from external module (jar)?

Tags: java, spring, gwt

Greetings,

We have been using our reusable "user-management" module which was written using Spring/Hibernate(using Doman-Model Pattern).We have used that module in several project integrating with Wicket,JSP and ZK frameworks.
Now I am going to develop an application using GWT.I am completely new to GWT and I noticed that the domain objects should go inside "xxx.xxxx.client" package.
But I want to use our reusable module (jar) and the domain model is in completely different package.
How can I use my domain-model object from this external library in GWT?
How about service interfaces? Do I have to write proxies for them too?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your domain-model object to be used on the client side (ie: to be translated in javascript), you need to provide the sources to GWT during compile time. You also need to tell GWT in a module which package name you need to compile. See [how to organize projects in GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules).

About the GWT service interfaces, I'd suggest you to integrate GWT with Spring. There is a [nice tutorial about how integrating GWT with Spring](http://technophiliac.wordpress.com/2008/08/24/giving-gwt-a-spring-in-its-step/). The RPC calls of GWT could be then be routed to your existing services.

Hope it helps.